# How to pass arguments within docker-compose?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

Docker 1.9 allows to pass arguments to a dockerfile. 
See link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

How can I pass the same arguments within docker-compose.yml?
Please provide an example too, if possible.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This feature was added in Compose file format 1.6.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        FOO: foo
```

Comment: When I run `docker-compose version` it says 1.29.1 and that, as of this time of writing, is the latest.  1.6?

Comment: @volvox  he was referring the `Compose file format`  (Compose) , you are referring to `docker-compose`, different things. 1.6 is deprecated now. This post is quite old :)

Answer (score 103):

This can now be done as of docker-compose v2+ as part of the `build` object;

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    my_image_name:
        build:
            context: . #current dir as build context
            args:
                var1: 1
                var2: c
```

See [the docker compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

In the above example "var1" and "var2" will be sent to the build environment.

Note: any env variables (specified by using the `environment` block) which have the same name as `args` variable(s) will override that variable.

Comment: @tfg Do you know if the `args` keys need to be lowercase? The docs and all of the examples I've seen use lowercase keys, but I haven't seen any mention of that being _required_.

Comment: @pdoherty926 This should just be bash variable expansion, so uppercase and lowercase with underscores should be fine.

Comment: @tfg Thanks. I came to that conclusion myself in the meantime. Do you have any idea why the docs/examples use that convention?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for stacks: "This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file. The docker stack command accepts only pre-built images" from https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Comment: @tgallacher AFAIK, the variables in the `environment` block don't override `args` variables. It's just that `args` variables are available during the container **build process**, but `environment` variables are available while the container is **running**.

Answer (score 101):

Now `docker-compose` supports variable substitution.

Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which `docker-compose` is run. For example, suppose the shell contains `POSTGRES_VERSION=9.3` and you supply this configuration in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
db:
  image: "postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"
```

When you run `docker-compose up` with this configuration, Compose looks for the `POSTGRES_VERSION` environment variable in the shell and substitutes its value in. For this example, Compose resolves the `image` to `postgres:9.3` before running the configuration.

Comment: Build arguments is a Docker 1.9 feature, the question asked how to get Docker Compose to use them. Variable substitution is unrelated.

Comment: @Jack I know this is not a direct answer to the question, but it could be a workaround since the `docker-compose` doesn't support passing arguments.

Comment: @Jack I came here looking for variable substitution so this was helpful to me

Comment: Will be using the this for the time being. Can't use `docker-compose run` to pass in arguments as the argument has to be passed to multiple containers.

Comment: Is there a way to set a default value in one place? We've been doing `${PLATFORM_VERSION:-v1.0.0}` all over and it would be nice to just put the default in one spot.

Comment: @weberc2 I know at this time you should have figured out but I'll leave it here for others. You can set it as an environment with a default value in your `docker-compose.yml` file. 
`environment:\n  PLATFORM_VERSION: "${PLATFORM_VERSION:-v1.0.0}"`. PS: `\n` is just because I couldnt find a way to format multiline code block in comments.

Answer (score 9):

1. Create a variable environment on Linux shell:

   ```
   export TAG=0.1.2
   ```
2. Set variable inside docker-compose.yml

   ```
   db:
     image: "redis:${TAG}"
   ```
3. Verify if value was replaced

   ```
   docker-compose config
   ```

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer. Thanks for share it!

Answer (score 7):

Something to add to these answers that the `args` are picked up only when using `docker-compose up --build` and not when using `docker-compose build`. If you want to build and run in separate steps, you need use `docker-compose build --build-arg YOUR_ENV_VAR=${YOUR_ENV_VAR}`or `docker build --build-arg YOUR_ENV_VAR=${YOUR_ENV_VAR}`

Comment: Not sure if something changed but I've just built with `docker-compose build` and the build took my variables on the docker-compose.yml file just fine. No need to use --build-arg.

Comment: `docker compose build --build-arg USERNAME=xxx` did not work for me. It says `WARN[0000] The "USERNAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

Comment: @M.Gleria: perhaps the api is updated now

Comment: @igor: Its possible the apis for `docker-compose` and `docker compose` are different (the latter was introduced later)