# Can I pass arguments into docker-compose the command config option

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rstudio-server

Anyone know how I can use the command: option in docker-compose to run my command with arguments?  I know version 2 offers arguments, but that works with docker-engine 1.10.x  I am on docker-engine 1.6.2 and cannot upgrade at the moment.

I want to do something like this in docker-compose:

```
...
rstudio:
  image: rocker-hadleyverse
  command: -d -p 8787:8787 -e USER=<username> -e PASSWORD=<password> rocker-hadleyverse
  links:
    - db
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments within docker-compose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose is a different issue - I want to pass arguments to the command option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please (re)read the docker-compose [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), in docker-compose.yml `command` refers to the actual command executed inside the container, not the options you pass to `docker run`. Your example translates to:

```
rstudio:
  image: rocker-hadleyverse
  ports:
    - "8787:8787"
  environment:
    - USER=foo
    - PASSWORD=bar
  links:
    - db
```

To detach after container start use `docker-compose up -d`.

Comment: But how can I start a docker-compose with values passed in?

Comment: For `docker-compose up` you only have [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) and the [env-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/). For `run` you can also use `-e` like with `docker run`.

Comment: I think this is actually possible now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928257/3757322