# How to set Docker-compose arguments in console?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My Docker containers will be set up through a bash script.

In my docker-compose.yml file (which is called through `docker-compose up` inside the bash file) I have a few arguments:

```
version: "2"
services:
    nginx:
        build: ./Dockerfiles/wordpress-nginx
        expose:
            - "80"
        depends_on:
            - fpm
        links:
            - fpm
        container_name: wordpress-nginx
        args:
            - site_title=Example
            - admin_email=test@test.co
            - site_url=www.testcase001.com
            - admin_user=admin
            - admin_pass=qwerty
            - ssl_domain=www.testcase001.com
            - dbname=testcase
            - dbuser=testcase
            - dbpass=testcase
            - dbhost=testcase
    fpm:
        build: ./Dockerfiles/php-fpm
        expose:
            - "9000"
        container_name: fpm
```

Now my question is this:

***How can I set the arguments from the command line?***

For example:
I want to set the `site_title` argument: `docker-compose up --something-to-set-the-site_title-argument`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments within docker-compose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose)

Comment: Specifically this answer, which shows how to use environment variables for parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35095444/1228454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use environment variables in your `docker-compose.yaml` file, e.g.:

```
args:
  - site_title: $SITE_TITLE
```

In your Bash script, you can then set the title environment variable like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SITE_TITLE="My new title"

docker-compose up -d
```

The `$SITE_TITLE` environment variable should then be used in your compose configuration.

Comment: If I ever meet the person who invented this... f**king awesome. Thanks mate