# Docker compose args return of linux command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set an `arg` for docker compose using an output of linux command as my example:

```
args:
     ID_GITLAB: $(id -u $USER)
```

but when I run my compose I get following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "build" option in service "gpc-fontes-ci": "$(id -u $USER)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments within docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose)

Comment: I don't think you can invoke shell functions within Compose. Where did you learn that you could?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I escape a $ dollar sign in a docker compose file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619582/how-can-i-escape-a-dollar-sign-in-a-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
USER_ID=$(id -u $USER) docker-compose
```

With the Compose file using a regular variable

```
args:
     ID_GITLAB: $USER_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape `$` character with another `$`, e.g.

```
args:
     ID_GITLAB: $$(id -u $USER)
```

It's the same rule for `command`.

See: [Variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).

> You can use a `$$` (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a value, so a `$$` allows you to refer to environment variables that you don’t want processed by Compose.

For example:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: "$$VAR_NOT_INTERPOLATED_BY_COMPOSE"
```