# dockerd set default environment variable for all containers

Tags: docker

I have a docker daemon running behind an HTTP proxy.

My `Dockerfile`'s look like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc
```

Normally I configure the proxy by adding the `http_proxy` environment variable to the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV http_proxy http://myproxy.mydomain.com:8080/

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc
```

And that works fine.

But I don't want to touch the `Dockerfile` because it is also used in other environments where the proxy isn't available. I don't want to have `ENV http_proxy ...` in the `Dockerfile` at all.

So my question is: how to add an environment variable to all containers **without touching** the `Dockerfile`s?

Comment: @rustyxI posted my answer try this below

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose/35095444#35095444

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG HTTP_PROXY_ARGUMENT

ENV http_proxy ${HTTP_PROXY_ARGUMENT}

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc
```

Build like below

```
docker build -t --build-arg HTTP_PROXY_ARGUMENT=http://myproxy.mydomain.com:8080/ imagename .
```

Answer (score 0):

With adding a environment variable on run ?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables