# Pass argument to docker-compose yml when calling up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a command to be executed in my `docker-compose.yml` with `docker-compose up --build -d`:

```
(...)
command: certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot \
         -d test.apps.example.com
```

but I would like to have something like this:

```
(...)
command: certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot \
         -d ${arg}.example.com
```

and: `docker-compose up --build -d "test.apps"`

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker-compose supports variable substitution. It reads env from your working shell. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

In your compose file:

```
command: certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot \
         -d ${SUB_DOMAIN}.example.com
```

In you shell, export the variable:

```
export SUB_DOMAIN=test.apps
```

then

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: This is it, what I was actually looking for was `docker-compose run -e VAR=anything` but it is essentially the same but inline.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for build args:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/

```
Usage: docker-compose build [options] [--build-arg key=val...] [SERVICE...]

Options:
--compress              Compress the build context using gzip.
--force-rm              Always remove intermediate containers.
--no-cache              Do not use cache when building the image.
--pull                  Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
-m, --memory MEM        Sets memory limit for the build container.
--build-arg key=val     Set build-time variables for services.
--parallel              Build images in parallel.
```

and [How to pass arguments within docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose)