# docker-compose file cannot download maven dependencies from private nexus repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently i am using docker ee in which multi build is not supported. So i am using named volume to store data from one container and use the same data for another container.
I made 2 Docker files in which 1 docker file get the project from git repository and in 2nd file it uses maven to run that project.
The thing is it is working fine when you run both of them separately but then i tried with docker-compose it is failing to download dependencies from private nexus repository.Do i have to provide anything in docker-compose file inorder to pull dependencies from private repository.It shows unknown host repositry

Dockerfile_git-

```
FROM alpine/git
MAINTAINER Tejas
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan <<host>> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
WORKDIR /share
RUN git clone <<url>>
```

Dockerfile_mvn-

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine
MAINTAINER Tejas
WORKDIR /share/trainingcontainers/
RUN echo $MAVEN_HOME
RUN rm -f $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml
COPY ./settings.xml $MAVEN_HOME/conf/
WORKDIR /share/trainingcontainers/selenium-grid/Website_Login
CMD mvn clean install
```

```
version: "3"
services:
  task1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_git
    volumes:
      - "myshare2:/share"
  task2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_mvn
    volumes:
      - "myshare2:/share"
volumes:
    myshare2:
```

Compose file logs-

```
task2_1  | [INFO] --------------------< Website_Login:Website_Login >---------------------
task2_1  | [INFO] Building Website_Login 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
task2_1  | [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
task2_1  | Downloading from nexus: http://<<hostname>>/repository/maven-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
task2_1  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
task2_1  | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
task2_1  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
task2_1  | [INFO] Total time: 6.003 s
task2_1  | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-01T10:15:01Z
task2_1  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
task2_1  | [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to nexus (http://<<hostname>>/repository/maven-public/): <<hostname>>: Try again: Unknown host <<hostname>>: Try again -> [Help 1]
```

settings.xml -

```
<mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://<<hostname>>/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
            <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
            <sonar.host.url>
                http://localhost:9000
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Hello Tejas, welcome to Stackoverflow!
Can you please provide both Dockerfiles?

Comment: @EmreIşık i shared the files

Comment: @TejasShetty could you also paste you docker compose logs in the question? That will give us a more clear picture of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @YugSingh i have shared the logs

Comment: @TejasShetty as you can see in the logs the docker compose is not able to resolve the hostname for the nexus repo. It might be because the docker-compose is setting it's own network where it is running the container and the host info is not available in the network. Whereas when you do docker run your nexus repo hostname info. is available on the host where docker daemon is running.

Comment: @TejasShetty you need to specify the host of nexus repo in docker-compose.yml file. I think you can look into environment variables and see if there is a way to do so using that.

Comment: @YugSingh went through internet searching the same, please do share if you find anything. thanks

Comment: @TejasShetty is it possible to use environment var. in your docker file and then set that from your compose.yml?

Comment: @YugSingh yes i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution you just need to add following line-

network_mode: "bridge"

According to my docker compose file-

```
version: "3"
services:
  task1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_git
    volumes:
      - "myshare2:/share"
  task2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_mvn
    network_mode: "bridge"
    volumes:
      - "myshare2:/share"
volumes:
    myshare2:
```

Answer (score 0):

You say they work fine when you run them separately. Can you post the commands you use for that?

It might be that you use in there a parameter that you didn't put in the docker-compose.

Another thing: docker-compose creates its own network which normally is a bridge network but it might have a different setup on your machine. You can check the networks configured on your machine:

```
docker network ls
```

Comment: Hello Mihai first i created a named volume - docker volume create --name --myshare then i built both dockerfiles  -docker build –f Dockerfile_git –t git_image .
-docker build –f Dockerfile_mvn –t mvn_image .
then i used run command like this            
 -docker run –v myshare:/share git_image ,docker run –v myshare:/share mvn_image

Comment: that looks about right. But then who is "repository"? Do you reference it in your settings.xml? Also when you run them with docker-compose, do you allow the first one to finish cloning and then start the second one?

Comment: as i mentioned above it is a private nexus repository and yes i have referenced it in my settings.xml file and it is working fine as i am able to pull the dependencies without docker-compose file but when i try to run it with docker-compose it gives unknown host error(you can see it as i provided the logs above) and yes the first file clones first and then the 2nd file starts.

Comment: I saw the logs after. I understand you obfuscate the hostname which is good. but you have <<host>> and <<hostname>>. Are they actually different or not? If they are different then it is really weird... I just tried with my Nexus server and I could build having a similar docker-compose.yml

Comment: i was trying to mask it my bad , both of them are the same thing . plus i shared my settings.xml, if it is running with your repository do compare the files

Comment: I read a bit better the error: unknown host could mean that it cannot resolve the DNS name. Is there a possibility to use the IP of your nexus server instead of the hostname?

Comment: it's not permanent. just to see if it works. If it does then you can add the nexus server as an "extra_host" in your docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environemnt variables to pass value dynamically when an image is built from **Dockerfile** as shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).

Similarly you can use the **args** to pass variables from **compose.yml** to container which it starts as shown below(referred from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args)):

```
 services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        var1: c
        var2: d
```

Now "var1" and "var2" will be sent to the build environment.

Also, you may try the below approach as **docker-compose** supports variable substitution also([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34322631/6407858)).

Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which **docker-compose** is run. For example, suppose the shell contains `HOST_NAME=test.org` and you supply this configuration in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
    db:
      image: "test:${HOST_NAME}"
```

Comment: @TejasShetty Pls look at the above answer and see whether it helps

Comment: build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_mvn
      args:
        hostname: <hostname>  and while running the compose file it is pasing the value-  RUN echo "host_name: $hostname"
 ---> Running in 134b9badee59

host_name: <<hostname>>
still facing same issue