# Pass argument to Dockerfile from a file with docker-compose (SSH private key)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi!

I'm kinda stuck in docker-compose, as I need to pass my private SSH key to my `Dockerfile` declared in my `docker-compose.yml`, as below:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  worker:
    build: .
    args:
      - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/  && \
    echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

With docker itself, that's quite easy, as I just need to run the following command:

```
docker build . --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
```

But in docker-compose... The problem of the `ARGS` configuration in docker-compose as described [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose) is that I can't let the private key inside the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I need to let docker-compose access to the key inside `~/.ssh/id_rsa`: Any clue on how to perform that?

Thank you!

Comment: Remember that, if you do this, anyone who can has the image can trivially extract the private key (in this case both by `docker run` the image and by looking at its `docker history`).  I'd recommend keeping your ssh keys and your Dockerfiles separate, and if you need to check out source repositories, do that on the host before running any Docker operations.

Comment: @DavidMaze if the key is inside a variable provided during the build phase, it should not be stored in the image right? That's why I do not wanted to add the private key inside the Dockerfile itself, and provide it as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs on args](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) states that :

> You can omit the value when specifying a build argument, in which case its value at build time is the value in the environment where Compose is running.

In your case, you probably want to build `worker` service with the following command :

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" docker-compose build
```

By the way, your `docker-compose.yml` is wrong (missing `context`) and should be :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now! And indeed your'e right, I forgot to add the context in that example :-)