# Pass args to image in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently, my docker-compose.yml is building an image.  I have an image from a 3rd party that I need to add alongside my own, which my own image will be dependent on.  When running the 3rd party image independently, I need to pass an argument to it like this:

```
docker run third_party/image --argument_flag
```

How do I translate this into the docker-compose.yml so that the argument_flag gets passed.  Here is my yml (names have been generalized).

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app_folder
    depends_on: 
      - "third_party"
  third_party:
    image: third_party/image
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your argument by overriding the default [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command)

Answer (score 0):

In Dockerfile you can get the argument ARGUMENT:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg PRODUCTION=VALUE
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG ARGUMENT
FROM node:latest
```

or try to check it out:
[How to pass arguments within docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322631/how-to-pass-arguments-within-docker-compose)
seems like the answer has been already there

Comment: args are for build, not image

Comment: @MattMcNair might you mean, Image not container?

Answer (score -2):

In docker-compose file you can add like this. 'args' tag in docker-compose file represent the argument same as docker run.

```
  third_party:
    image: third_party/image
    args:
       some_variable_name: some_value
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
```

Comment: args are for build not image