# docker apache volume not working properly

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
services:
  apache:
    container_name: apache
    build: ./docker/apache/
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
  php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./docker/php
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    working_dir: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    networks:
      - backend
```

**apache.conf**

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/$1

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/public>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[image]
As you can see Project folder Directory. when try to access http://localhost:8002/ it's not show public folder in browser index of.

[image]

When Change the Directory path in apache.conf **File not found.** error message is showing on browser

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/public>
```

PHP Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libmcrypt-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo
```

Apache Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4.51
COPY apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/apache.conf

RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: have any solution?

Comment: `./src` you should resolve the path... a relative path changes with the current working directory, so better to make absolutely sure to use the right path by using an absolute path :)

Answer (score 2):

Since all your other files are showing up it's most likely a permissions issue. Your `public` directory is probably owned by the `apache` or `http` or `www-data` user on your host system and that user's `uid` and/or `gid` do not match what is being used inside the container. You can find out the ids of the host user like this...

First, determine the right username :

```
ls -l ./src/public
```

Then get the `uid` of that user :

```
id -u www-data
```

And the `gid` :

```
id -g www-data
```

Finally, append the below lines to your apache `Dockerfile`, replacing the `ARG` values with the results of the above commands :

```sh
ARG UID=33
ARG GID=33
RUN usermod -u ${UID} www-data \
&& usermod -g ${GID} www-data \
&& chown -hR www-data:www-data /usr/local/apache2
```

The official `httpd` image that you are using runs as the user `www-data` so do not change that in the `usermod` commands, we are just changing the ids of the existing user in the container to match your host system.

To make this more flexible/portable you can also [pass the values in from your compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323757/6036546).

#### Alternatively

For a quick and dirty fix, just do `chmod -R a+r ./src/public` on the host. This will probably work but is less secure. However, if you are just testing things out or only setting up this project for personal use then this may be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try instead the [`--mount` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag), with a full path as source, on `docker run`:

```
 --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/src,target=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It specifies a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#choose-the-right-type-of-mount), which means a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container.

---

Check also the output of [`docker inspect yourContainer`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/), in order to see what volume has been set up.